# Hide iFrame when you click anywhere outside its boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Im looking for the iframe to close when i click away from it.

I have tried some jQuery but it was unsuccessful:

```
$('body').click(function(event){

if($(event.target).parents('#mainFrame_Example').length <= 0)
     $('#mainFrame_Example').hide();
})
```

Heres the code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title generic-modal-title">Select</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body generic-modal-body">
        <div style="max-height:400px; overflow:scroll;">
            <iframe src="blahblahblah.aspx" id="mainFrame_Example" width="100%" height="400px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you make a `div` spreading through the whole `body` and append the event `click` to it? This `div` should wrap all the contents as parent element.

Comment: And this one `id="mainFrame_Example"` is terrible. HTML is case insensitive. What's the point of using capital letters? Mixing of snake and camel case makes it also prone to reading errors. Better use `id="main-frame-example"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).add(parent.document).click(function(e) {
    var iframe = $('iframe');
    if (!iframe.is(e.target) && iframe.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        iframe.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do,

```
$(function(){

   $('body').on('click', function () {
       $('#mainFrame_Example').hide();
   });

});
```